# How to replace duplicate elements in Hash Map

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, maps

I'm trying to replace duplicate values in Hash Map with new unique ids. so that order of elements is not lost but duplicate values alone get changed to new ones.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();      
  hm.put(100,"1111111111");    
  hm.put(101,"5252");    
  hm.put(102,"1111111111");
  hm.put(103,"1111111111");

  for(int i=0;i<hm.size;hm++){
  String uuids = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
  hm.put(i, uuids);
  }
```

Comment: *order of elements* - use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve order instead of `HashMap`

Comment: okay. how to replace the duplicate values then?

Comment: What if there are *2 or more sets* of duplicates?

Comment: they have to be replaced by uuids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close:

```
Map<Integer, String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
hm.put(100, "1111111111");
hm.put(101, "5252");
hm.put(102, "1111111111");
hm.put(103, "4589857");

Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : hm.entrySet()) {
    if (!seen.add(e.getValue())) { //if (the 'seen' set already has that value)
        hm.replace(e.getKey(), UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
    }
}

System.out.println(hm);
```

Output:

```
{100=1111111111, 101=5252, 102=ba297d9412654591826d4e496f643b4c, 103=4589857}
```

Answer (score 1):

First,reverse the key and value in your `hm` map into a `Multimap`，then rewrite value to your own map.code like this:

```
Multimap<String,Integer> reverseMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
hm.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(integerStringEntry -> reverseMap.put(integerStringEntry.getValue(),integerStringEntry.getKey()));
reverseMap.keySet().forEach(s -> reverseMap.get(s).stream()
    .skip(1L)
    .forEach(integer -> {
        String uuids = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        hm.put(integer,uuids);
    }));

System.out.println(hm);
```

The output is：

```
{100=1111111111, 101=5252, 102=2e3586d248e3413687ff55dc17817c7d, 103=4589857}
```